# Swift 3 Show Segue not working on a different machine

Tags: swift, macos, segue

I am trying to open a new Window with a pop up showing an overview of the main window. For that I chose Show Segue. On my machine it opens in a new window and works as I intend it - it's a pop up in a different window that is independent of the original window. However, on a friend's machine, the segue overrides his main Window. 
Any ideas what's causing this? I have a custom segue class defined for travelling between windows for other screens, however I have not specified that class in that specific segue. 
Both machines running Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: Would really help if you showed some code otherwise it could be just a guessing game. What are the screen sizes? Is display set to default or scaled?

Comment: I can show the code, however the problem in question is using the XCode's default Show segue and all I am performing in the transition is: 

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showOverviewScreen", sender:self)